# C++ insertion sort

Tags: c++, insertion-sort

I have this function called WordSort(worddata W [], int count) that is fed two variables 
1 - worddata is the array holding information on a given word in a file. count is just the counter variable to see which word in the array we are looking at.

the words.txt file that is read into this program would just be a string of words.

```
this is a list of words
there are letters and numbers
23 people recommend this program.
```

Heres the function:

```
void WordSort (worddata W [], int count)
{
  for (int i=1; i < count; i++)
         {
           for (int j=i; j > 0 && W[j-1].word > W[j].word; j--)
             {
               Swap(W[j], W[j-1]);
             }
         }
}
```

The swap function is suppose to swap every element with the one before it as long as j > 0 or the list is over. Im confused on how to complete the swap function, here's the example i was given.

```
void Swap (worddata & a, worddata & b)
{
 int += a;
 a = b;
 b =+;
}
```

Swap is suppose to swap every element with the one before it

I think the WordSort function works fine, the only thing missing is the Swap function. Could anyone point me in the right direction or explain insertion sorting better to me?

Comment: can you provide example on words? what is expected result?

Comment: `int += a;` and `b =+;` are not valid C++ code.  And isn't this a bubble sort?

Comment: is this real code? does it compile?

Comment: Explain just what Swap is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: I don't suppose [`std::swap()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) would make your life a little easier.

Comment: the whole point is to make our own swap function - i had already looked into that though!

Comment: Then you know what it should look like, so what is that... thing... you were given for example?

Comment: I'm assuming the plus sign is meant to be the letter 't' in the `swap` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap should look like this -- I have no idea how your example is even close.

```
void Swap (worddata & a, worddata & b)
{
 worddata temp = a;
 a = b;
 b = temp;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why worddata has to go in front of temp? I had tried this without it and it wouldnt compile

Comment: Because you need a "local" variable, this is declaring "temp" as an local variable where you will store "a", and of course, worddata is the data type... note that maybe "wordata" is different to int

Comment: @nastalgia if this doesn't compile it is likely `worddata` doesn't support either copy construction or an assignment operator (or both?). Otherwise this should compile correctly.

Comment: It compiles and works perfectly. Thank you @Gary Walker and friends - i understand this code so much better now that it is complete

Comment: I think using std::swap is better

Comment: I think for someone with this level of understanding, they need to learn a little more about how to code than how to use the standard library. std::swap is perfect once you betting understanding of how to write c++.

Comment: @nastalgia: if you don't understand the temp declaration statement, you really, really need to open a C++ book and read about the language syntax. Basics and foundations should come first.

Answer (score 3):

```
void insertion_sort()
{


    /* Algorithm : Insertion Sort
     * Coded by .
    */
    int num;
    /*
     * Asking the User no of Integers he/she wants to enter
     */
    cout << "Enter no of integers u want to enter: ";
    cin >> num;
    /* Creating an Array to store the integers*/
    int s[num];
    /*Taking Integers from the User */
    for(int i = 0 ; i < num ; i++)
    {
        cout << "Integer " << i+1 << " is : ";
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        s[i] = x;
    }
    /* The Magic of INSERTION SORT */
    for(int j = 1 ; j <= (num-1) ; j++)
    {
        int key = s[j]; 
        int k = j-1;

        while(k >=0 && key <= s[k])
        {
            s[k+1] = s[k];
            k = k - 1;
        }
        s[k+1]=key;

    }
    /*Printing Out the Sorted List */
    cout << "The Sorted List is \n\n";
    for(int i = 0 ; i < num ; i++)
    {
        cout << s[i] << "  ";
    }

}
```

Comment: Interesting, the array is defined from 0 to num but we iterate from 1 to num-1. Upvoted because the hole at k = j -1 when j is zero is plugged, but does it work for num + 1 integers?

Answer (score 2):

Use standard library [std::swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) instead. In your loop:

```
for (...)
{
    std:swap(W[j], W[j-1]);
}
```

std::swap requires worddata class to have a copy constructor and an assignment operator defined explicitly or implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

### Insertion sort using "for loop" (2 iterations)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int insertion(int arr[], int size_arr)
{
    int i,j,n, temp;

    for(i=1;i<size_arr; i++){
            j=i-1;
            temp = arr[i];
            for (j; j >=  0; j--)
        {
            if(arr[j] > temp){
                        arr[j+1] = arr[j];
                        arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
            arr[j] = temp;
      }

    for(i=0;i<size_arr;i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    int arr[] = {3,38,1,44,66,23,105,90,4,6};
    int size_arr = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    insertion(arr,size_arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>


void printArr(int arr[], int size)
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        std::cout << arr[i] << " "; 

    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

void insertionSort(int arr[],int size){
    for (int i=1; i<size; i++){
        int temp=arr[i];
        int prev=i-1;
        while( prev>=0 && arr[prev]>temp )
        {
            arr[prev+1]=arr[prev];
            arr[prev]=temp;
            prev = prev-1;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[]={5,4,8,2,1};
    insertionSort(arr,5);
    printArr(arr,5);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer). In particular, you should explain how your answer improves on those posted some years ago.